# Where can I catch the unicorn horn?

Tags: candy-box-2

I need the unicorn horn to increase the rate of lollipop and I arrived at the castle. Where can I find it?

Comment: Adding the English translation in a comment is appreciated, but if you can phrase your question in English, please use English instead of another language.

Comment: The horn doesn’t increase lollipop-production rate, it increase health-recovery rate. The pitchfork increase lollipop-production.

Answer (score 1):

It is in a chest in the desert temple, first room.